# response = request.urlopen(image_url) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Python 2.7.10 and urllib3 are on my computer.
Following is my forms.py file:

```
from urllib3 import request
......
class ImageCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
      def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False,
                commit=True):
......
response = request.urlopen(image_url)
```

After running server in terminal I got error like this:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'

How can I fix it?

Comment: The documentation for `urllib3` makes no mention of a `urlopen` function. It does mention a `urlopen` method on some internal objects (namely HTTPConnectionPool and PoolManager). Are you sure that's what you should be using?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of urllib3](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) does not contain a function called urlopen.

You might prefer working with [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) which has the function urlopen.

Answer (score -1):

`request` object doesn't have a `urlopen` attribute. How to fix? Add one, of course!

```
from urllib3 import request
import requests

request.urlopen = requests.get
...
response = request.urlopen(image_url)
```